# Loading data in ng-repeat after $http

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to load a number of elements in a div from json via  $http call. But whatever I try the list remains empty. Here is the code.

```
  <div class="submenu" >
            <div class="menuitem" ng-repeat="item in navigator"  >{{item}}
                <a href="#/main/welcome/{{item.messageId}}">{{item.label}}</a>
    </div>
```

It is an abstract state and I have assigned controller greetingctrl to it in routes. The JS code is

```
app.controller('greetingCtrl',function($scope,$cookieStore,$timeout,$state,msg,SERVICE,RestService,$stateParams){

    $scope.list = [];
    $scope.navigator;

    $scope.options.loading = false;
    var currentmsg;
    $scope.user = $cookieStore.get('userinfo');


    $scope.init = function(){           
        var url = SERVICE.greetingMsg;
        var data = {
            providerID : $cookieStore.get('userinfo').providerId,
            loginID : $cookieStore.get('userinfo').loginId,
            action : "GET_MESSAGE"
        }
        RestService.post(url,data).then(function(res){   
            $scope.navigator = res.messages;
        },
        function(err){
            console.log(err);

        });
    }
```

Here I can successfully receive the data but the data in the list never comes. RestService.post is $http method I have defined in a service.I am using angular 1.5.8 and I am new to angular.

**EDIT:** Removed ng-show and ng-if. Still the data is nnot showing

Comment: If you view the res.messages in the console, do you se the complete json? console.log(res.messages);

Comment: I can see it as array of objects. When I do res it is complete json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check two variables:
- `showmenu` I don't see its value changing at all so it's always `false`.
- `loadingisDone` same as the previous.

And remember to call `$scope.init` somewhere.

Comment: showmenu is a toggle I created to toggle the menu to show. I have removed both of these conditions and still the data is not showing.

Comment: @SarangKhajuria is `res.messages` returned correctly as array ? or string like array ?

Comment: It is returning an array.

Comment: tried to change variable name from `navigator` to anything else ?

Comment: of course you're calling `$scope.init` somewhere in your code !

Comment: Ah I am too dumb. This worked. Thanks for the hello. Please add it to your answer so I can mark it solved

Comment: Adding ng-init=init(); I had two files pointing to the same controller. There is more code which I removed for the sake of simplifying after I pinpointed problem. One had ng-init = init() and the other didn't. I had some other things to do with the res so I had to point two files here

Answer (score 0):

what is the ng-if tag contains, it should have some conditions to check
 
change to
  0'>
Try if it works

Comment: I have removed both of them and still it is not showing the data

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to use ng-if and ng-show both directives on same tag.
You can use either one to display that DIV by using **&&** and **||** operators.
Please check the if the value of variables are updating properly.

Comment: try assigning the variable to empty array $scope.navigator = [];

Answer (score -1):

For async execution use $scope.$apply to update your scoped data.

```
RestService.post(url,data).then(function(res){   
   $scope.$apply(function() {
      $scope.navigator = res.messages;
   });
}
```

Comment: Using `$scope.$apply` in angular's `.then` almost guarantee a `digest already in progress` error.